# Troubleshooting an Azure V2 (Azure Resource Manager) Public load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have built out an infrastructure in Azure using an ARM template (all resources mentioned will have been provisioned with the Resource Manager and not the classic model).

![Image of probe config] https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dco1t1lo9frtme/AzureLBProbe.png?dl=0

I am trying to troubleshoot a public facing load balancer.  I  have created a probe to a path that does not exist so I can demonstrate the load balancer's behavior of marking a host as "unavailable". I cannot find any log entry, event or notification that the Load Balancer has marked this host as unavailable.  I am hoping I am missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find any documentation on MSDN or anywhere else for that matter.  So to summarize, my question is how can I find out (via alert/notification/portal) that a public load balancer has marked an instance as unavailable?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, You may start with https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-monitor-log/ . It will not provide exactely the level of detail you need but this is work in progress

Comment: Are you able to provide some additional information about how your Backend Pool is configured - i.e. is it associated to an Availability Set, Single VM, or VM Scale Set?